# Is there a valid reason to allow leading or trailing spaces in user input?

Tags: input-fields, input, white-space

I want to propose a new guideline in our company to disallow leading or trailing spaces in any user input (web forms).

Is there **any** valid scenario where you want to allow leading or trailing spaces in user input?

<sup>One field that you could argue allowing this could be a password field,
 but I would disallow it for simplicities sake</sup>

Comment: *Do not* disallow anything in a password input field for any reason: it's a signal to your users that you don't know how to handle passwords correctly. Take any string, hash it, and store it as whatever (usually a hexadecimal string representation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on the type of form input:

**Usernames/Emails**

Trim away. Especially if you accept mobile input, as some auto-complete keyboards insert a trailing space after emails.

**Passwords**

As mentioned by others, do not trim. Treat spaces like any other alphanumeric/symbolic character.

**Text Paragraph Entry**

Just be careful here on implementation, as some languages' trim methods remove tabs and newlines. This may break formatted text.

*My answer here refers to "trimming", which in this case means the removal of spaces after the input has been received. This could also be achieved with client-side validation.*

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't blame the user with a validation error if he types a space as the last (or first) character of an input field: if you trim the input once submitted, there won't be any problem.

I cannot think of any common scenario where the input text won't be trimmed. Passwords would be an edge case. There are some input field that won't accept a space as a valid character, such as *E-mail address* field or numeric input, but this is an other story.